# Proof involving the infinite number of primes

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Given that
>
> $R = p_1p_2\cdots p_n + 1$ where $p_1 < p_2 < \cdots  < p_n$ and $p$ are prime numbers.
>
> Prove that if $R$ is not prime then $R$ must have a prime factor $q$ that is larger than $p_n$.

I directly understand that this question refers to Euclid's infinite primes proof however; Honestly, I don't know really how to even begin this problem.

Any advice on this problem would be very helpful and appreciated.

Comment: That's false as written; consider taking $p_1=3$ and $p_2=5$, for example, so that $R=16$ has only factors of $2$, which is less than $5$. It is important to state that $p_1<\cdots<p_n$ are the ***first*** $n$ prime numbers.

Comment: @ZevChonoles : Euclid's proof didn't say they were the first $n$ prime numbers, but only that they are some finite set of prime numbers.  (But it is true if they are the first $n$ prime numbers, then the prime factors of $R$ must be bigger than all of them.)

Comment: 'larger' here would be better as 'different than all the $p_i$'; this is still than enough to show that any finite list can't contain them all.

Comment: @Michael: Indeed, I'm only assuming that since the question asks for "larger", the source of the OP's question likely intended $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ to be the first $n$ primes, even though Euclid's proof is about any finite set of primes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not true: If $p_1=5$ and $p_2 = 7$, and that's your sequence, then $p_1 p_2 + 1$ has prime factors $2$ and $3$.  Those numbers are not bigger than $5$ and $7$.

What Euclid showed is that if you have any finite set of prime numbers, and you multiply them and then add $1$, then the prime factors of the number you get are *not in* the finite set you started with.  That's not the same as saying they're bigger than any of the numbers in the set you started with.  That's not true: sometimes they're actually smaller than all of them.

So you have some primes $p_1,\ldots,p_n$.  The number $R=(p_1\cdots p_n)+1$ leaves a remainder of $1$ when divided by any of $p_1,\ldots,p_n$; therefore it is divisible by none of them.  Its prime factors are therefore not in the set $\{p_1,\ldots,p_n\}$.

For example, consider

\begin{align}
888 & = 2\cdot3\cdot37 \\
889 & = 7\cdot127 \\
890 & = 2\cdot5\cdot89 \\
891 & = 3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot3\cdot11 \\
    & {}\  \vdots
\end{align}

The next number after $888$ cannot be $37$ because you don't get another number divisible by $37$ until you've gone $37$ steps beyond that, up to $888 + 37$.  It cannot be divisible by $3$ since you don't get another number divisible by $3$ until you get to $888+3$.  It cannot be divisible by $2$ since you don't get another number divisible by $3$ until you get to $888+2$.  Therefore its prime factors are not in the set $\{2,3,37\}$.

Comment: Very interesting, I will certainly look into this further. Thank you for the great response Michael!

Comment: Maybe I should warn you that many respectable mathematicians, Dirichlet among them, mistakenly say that what Euclid wrote was a proof by contradiction that began by assuming that only finitely many primes exist.  Once you've got that assumption, it follows that those finitely many primes have to be the smallest $n$ primes (for some $n$).  Even authors who don't present it as a proof by contradiction often begin by considering the smallest $n$ primes.  That's relatively (but maybe not completely) harmless, but it is historically false to say that that's how Euclid did it.

Comment: In 2009 a joint paper by me and Catherine Woodgold appeared in _The Mathematical Intelligencer_ debunking the historical error and explaining how Euclid's actual proof is better than some of those falsely reported to have been his proof.

Comment: Thank you Michael, that is a very interesting historical fact.

It can be found through the following link, in case anyone else here wants to read it: http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00283-009-9064-8