# Prove that if $R$ is not prime then $R$ must have a prime factor $q$ that is larger than $p_n$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

This is a modification of [my previous post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/675680/264) which has completely different meanings/solutions

> Given that
>
> $R = p_1p_2\cdots p_n + 1$ where $p_1 < p_2 < \cdots  < p_n$ and $p$ are the **first n prime numbers.**
>
> Prove that if $R$ is not prime then $R$ must have a prime factor $q$ that is larger than $p_n$.

I directly understand that this question refers to Euclid's primes proof however; I don't know really how to even tackle this problem. I am looking over euclid's proof and will hopefully run into a 'eureka' moment.

Any advice or tips on how to solve this problem would be very helpful and appreciated.

Comment: This was answered in your prior question. You know from that answer that the prime factors of $R$ are not among the first n primes, therefore they are all larger than the nth prime.

Comment: Sorry, I may have missed it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: If $R$ is not prime, then $R$ has a prime divisor. Convince yourself that this prime divisor isn't any of $p_1, ..., p_n$. Now use how $p_1, ..., p_n$ are defined.

Comment: Thank you for the response Tyler. I think I have figured it out!

1. q cannot be in the given set p
2. q is a prime divisor of R
3. Since q is not in the set p, which are the first primes in order, q must be greater than the greatest number in that list.

Comment: @AA Exactly right.